# Create Row with Equal Height Column of Image and Column of Scrollable List Group

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Does anyone know how to create two responsive Bootstrap 4 columns with the same height where one column is an image and the other is a scrollable list?

Here's a fiddle (note that I don't want the list group to exceed the height of the image as the viewport is resized): https://jsfiddle.net/lgants/gyk31vow/

I've literally spent days on this so any help would be greatly appreciated!

HTML:

```
<div class="row row-eq-height">
  <div class="col">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/sports-q-c-800-600-2.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="card">
      <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
img {
  max-width:100%;
  max-height:100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.list-group {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So what you need to do in this case is use JS to find the height of the image and set the height of the list equal to the height of the image. Also since Bootstrap 4 uses flex display on `row`s you need to set the `col`s to `align-items: start;` by giving the `row` a class of `align-items-start` I'm using Bootstrap v4-beta

```js
var picHeight = $('.pic-height').height();
$('.list-group').css('height', picHeight);

$(window).resize(function() {
 var picHeight = $('.pic-height').height();
 $('.list-group').css('height', picHeight);
});
```

```css
img {
  max-width:100%;
  max-height:100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.list-group {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="row row-eq-height align-items-start">
  <div class="col pic-height">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/sports-q-c-800-600-2.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="card">
      <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```